# iPhone 5S battery percentage incorrect after replacement

Tags: battery, iphone, repair

I've recently replaced the battery on my iPhone 5S (running latest iOS 10.2.1) and the battery percentage has been wrong ever since.

It originally showed around 50% (which I believe is what the original battery was at when I did the replacement), I then discharged the phone (which turned off with the battery still at 50%), then let it charge fully to 100% (when it came back up it showed 50% instead of the expected 1% or so).

I then let it drain again and it shut down at 90% (though battery life was great as it lasted several hours of full brightness + graphics intensive gaming), when it came back up it showed 90% again instead of around 1%. I let it charge fully.

Finally today I once again used the phone (expecting the battery meter to be calibrated) and despite great battery life the lowest the meter ever showed was 90% and it shut down. It's now on charge and came back up at around 90%.

One odd thing I noticed is that when it dies it shows the low battery screen when plugged in but only for a very short time before going straight to the Apple logo, where I would expect it to stick around on the charging screen for a few minutes at least.

I haven't restored it since the battery swap, I am not sure whether I should do that (I'd like to avoid it as it doesn't remember any of the e-mail nor wireless passwords and it's a pain to set them up again).

Regards.

Comment: The battery meter won’t be calibrated in one cycle, it’ll take a couple at least.

Comment: A restore didn't change anything, however connecting the original battery brought back the battery meter, so I just purchased a crap battery off a scammer (steer clear from iPhoneFixUK). Had to file a chargeback and buy another battery off iFixit, we'll see how good it is when it arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing the battery with another one (form iFixit), the battery meter is back to normal. I didn't think this would ever happen but I was so happy today seeing the battery level in the red instead of it being locked at 100%.

TLDR: the battery I bought was faulty and replacing it again fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what's going on, but I'd check this app to make sure it reports good health: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-life-check-devices-runtimes/id1080930585?mt=8.
If everything is good there, then I'd perform a hard reset, which you can do by holding the power and home buttons until the phone restarts and shows the Apple logo.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 5 has terrible battery life. Especially when you stream movies/tv or if you game alot. Unfortunately the battery has a memory. Meaning, if you were to charge it at say quarter to half life at a normal rate. It will eventually die in that said, percentage.

I understand that it's a replacement battery. I'm assuming you got it from Apple. I suggest you give Apple a call. They would have the best answers to your questions.

Speaking of replacement batteries. 
There is a process before replacing the battery.

1. Back up your data to iTunes or iCloud
2. Turn off "Find my iPhone"
3. Erase all contents and data

There are also many tips that will help decrease the battery usage in your settings. For example:

Push mail, Opting out for sending diagnostic data, Safari - settings, Gps, Etc

Hope I helped you out some. 
As I stated before, best to call Apple.

Comment: I Just wanted to add that iPhones use Lithium-ion batteries and these do not suffer from a “memory effect” the way NiCd batteries do.

Comment: I have had 2 iPhone 5s' the one dies at 32%, the other at 68%. The lithium-ion batteries hold on a lot longer then previous batteries, I agree. Although in the long run, it still depends on what you use the iPhone for. Gaming, streaming and using the hotspot are the major battery killers.